# Centering contents of li having inside bullet position, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: html, css, layout, html-lists

My goal is to centre items of an ordered list with their numbers. I am trying with `text-align: center`, it works, but the numbers are not centered, so I want to change `list-style-position` to `inside`.

But when I apply this, the numbered list transforms into a bulleted list!

Relevant code:

```
li {
    text-align: center;
    list-style: inside;
}
```

[Demo before `list-style`](http://jsfiddle.net/cx2Bz/) >> [Demo after `list-style`](http://jsfiddle.net/cx2Bz/1/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only change `list-style-position`, not the whole `list-style`.

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/cx2Bz/2/)

[`list-style`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/list-style) is a [shorthand property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Shorthand_properties) (like `background`, `font`, `margin`, etc.), it changes several properties at the same time. Namely it changes `list-style-type`, `list-style-position` and `list-style-image`. If you omit one of them (like you omitted `type` and `image`), the default value will be used instead. `disc` is default for `list-style-type`, so that is why it looks like an unordered list.

Answer (score 0):

well you can try this in your css code

```
li {
    text-align: center;
    list-style-position: inside
}
```

the list-style-position have to add...hope helped you...

Answer (score 0):

You want `list-style-position: inside`

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/cx2Bz/3/